# Flutter: I tried building a project just after adding flutter_local_notification to the dependencies and it failed

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, flutter

ERROR:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
>     /home/saugo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-27.1.0.aar/9fb468d34634c53fd038a8410ad263e8/res/values/values.xml:96:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>     /home/saugo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-27.1.0.aar/9fb468d34634c53fd038a8410ad263e8/res/values/values.xml:96:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>     error: failed linking references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
     compileSdkVersion 28
     }
 }
```

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: add this line in your `gradle.properties` file : android.enableJetifier = true

Comment: Sorry for the mess but the error is gone and I got the below error, although upon commenting out flutter_local_notifications in the dependencies , the error disappears and the toasts function well: /home/saugo/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-2.2.11/android/src/main/java/io/github/ponnamkarthik/toast/fluttertoast/FluttertoastPlugin.java:14: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                                 ^

Comment: I don't quite understand this solution. which build.gradle file is this? under android or android/app I already have compileSdkVersion but outside of defaultConfig under android {compileSdkVersion 27 defaultConfig { targetSdkVersion 27 }}, moving to 28 cause other errors with the app I am trying to build.